# How to create a complex class from a json request

Tags: http, dart, flutter, fetch

I have two different json that I want to cast in a single class "Response".
The first json gives me something like:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "asd",
   "objects": [
                "id" :  asd
                    ...
                  ]
               }]
```

and the other something like:

```
{
 id : 2
 name : "asd"
}
```

The class in which I'm trying to put them is

```
class Response {
  String name;
  int id;
  Objects object;
}
```

As you can see, the first one gives me back an array of elements, while the second not. I was trying with the `factory method`, but then I got stuck. So, is what I want to do possibile, or it's better to do in another way?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: you want to have a list of objects in the class response?

Comment: The JSON above is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Serializing JSON inside model classes](https://flutter.io/json/#serializing-json-inside-model-classes).

factory classes are a good start (I'm not sure what `Objects` is supposed to be in your example, your JSON is not valid):

```
factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Response(
    id: json['id'],
    name: json['name'],
    object: json['object'] == null ? null : Objects.fromJson(json['object'],
  );
}
```